# Changing collectionview button's image in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

**Tools**: xCode, Objective-C, Mac, Cocoa

**Purpose**: I am creating a collection view with many buttons. 
Each button opens a file in a folder and each of them has a background picture of the file (for example: jpeg file) so it looks like what you would see in a folder.

**Question**: **How to make each button have a different image?** Also, is this too difficult for a beginner?

**P.S.** : If i did this without the collectionview option, I would just drag the button on xib and change their background images, however I need my window to be collapsable and scrollable, hence I am using the collection view.

I would very much appreciate any comments/help/answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be difficult. A CollectionView holds a collection of CollectionViewItems. Inside the Item you can create any views you need. One of them could be an NSImageView that you set at runtime to the image you like. I suggest to play around with CollectionView and some f the samples Apple provides on it.

Comment: Thanks @harryhorn. I have played around with the Collection View, but still have questions. 

I understand that I create a Collection View Item with a button, but since I need the button to look different everytime, do I need to set that programmatically or adding more Collection View Items (if that's possible)?

I am fine when it come to changing text of the items in the NScollectionview, etc, but not good with changing images...

Comment: changing an image is no different than changing text. You set the relevant property with a new object. Good luck